# Self-hosting ASP.NET 5 within .NET 4.5 Application (without DNX and IIS)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dnx

Is it possible to add an ASP.NET 5 Web Application as a reference to a traditional .NET 4.5 project (Windows Service or Console App) and start it in-process?

Ideally within one solution, so that ASP.NET application and host service can share references to other projects in the same solution.

Tried so far:

`dnu publish` produces packages, but attempting to add them produces following error: *Install-Package : Could not install package 'WebApplication1 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework, Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.* When changing framework `dnx451` to `net451`, Web Application doesn't compile because of missing ASP references.

`dnu build` produces binaries, but how to run the application? (where to get *IApplicationBuilder* and *IHostingEnvironment* instances?)

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It is not possible to run an ASP.NET 5 application without DNX.

But you can run an ASP.NET 5 application without IIS. It can be self-hosted.

Comment: It seems it can run without DNX on IIS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939816/asp-net-v5-without-dnx

Comment: The answer provided is still using DNX.  dnu publish --runtime bundled a local copy of the dnx with the application.  So you don't need to seperately install a version of dnx (and possibly dnvm) on the server but you still have a dependency on dnx.  Following the linked solution and before deploying delete dnx from the publish folder and it will not work.